# AJAX POST DATA NOT WORKING

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my jQuery-Ajax code:

```
<script>
    $('#sbmt').click( function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: $("#ajxfrm").serialize(),
        url: "postdata.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data)
        {
          alert('updated table');
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML CODE:

```
<form id="ajxfrm" method="post" action=""> 

<label>HIGH :  </label>  <input type="text" name="hi"  id="hi"><br><br>

<label>LOW :  </label><input type="text" name="lo"  id="lo"><br><br>

<label>OPENING STOCK :  </label><input type="text" name="opn" id="opn"><br><br>

<label>CLOSING STOCK :  </label><input type="text" name="cls" id="cls">

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sbmt">

</form>
```

AND PHP CODE ON postdata.php file is :

```
require_once 'config.php';

$hi  = $_POST['hi'];

$lo = $_POST['lo'];

$opn = $_POST['opn'];

$cls = $_POST['cls'];

echo $hi;

$postdata = "INSERT INTO htmdem ( high,low,open,close ) VALUES('$hi','$lo','$opn','$cls');";

mysql_query($postdata);
```

When posting via form without ajax the table is getting updated as it should, but while using AJAX its not. Please suggest what's wrong here. Many Thanks

Comment: does it call the success function?

Comment: Is it showing any error in the browser console ?

Comment: Add an error callback; also, you are highly prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @RajuRudru: None what so ever

Comment: As Cory mentioned add an error callback

Comment: the problem is the form is submitting before the ajax request is complete, use `return false` as per @Khanh TO's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : Dont forget to set the form action to **postdata.php**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#ajxfrm').submit( function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            url: $(this).attr("action")
        })
                .done(function (data){
                    alert('updated table');
                });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: The changes here is not the **e.preventDefault();** one. But wrapping your code with **jQuery(function($){})**.  The code make sure to run if everything is being loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your html to add action to form:

```
<form id="ajxfrm" method="post" action="postdata.php">
```

Try handling form submit event instead:

```
$('#ajxfrm').submit(function(event){
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data)
        {
          alert('updated table');
        }
        });
       return false; //to prevent form submission
      //or event.preventDefault();
    });
```

BTW, using success callback is deprecated and post requests are not cached so we also don't need `cache:false`

```
$('#ajxfrm').submit(function(event){
      $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            url: $(this).attr("action")
            })
            .done(function (data){
               alert('updated table');
            });
           return false; //to prevent form submission
           //or event.preventDefault();
     });
```

Comment: I usually use `return false` too, but I was told that `prevent Default` is the preferred method. what do you think?

Comment: @andrew: `return false;` is `prevent default` and `stop propagation`. Prevent default could be enough in this case.

Comment: Likewise, add a `.fail()` to capture the failures: `$.ajax({ }).done(...).fail(...);`

Comment: @sanki: It could be that the form action is empty

Comment: @KhanhTO: Yes it was but when I added action="postdata.php" it's redirecting to postdata.php page.

Comment: @sanki: did you add `return false;` at the end?

Comment: @KhanhTO:  YES I literally copy pasted your code in my page :D

Comment: @sanki: hmm, it should not redirect when we `return false;`. Is there any error in the console?

Comment: @KhanhTO: None what so ever.

Comment: @sanki: Can you try `event.preventDefault();` ?

Answer (score 2):

change your input type="submit" to input type="button". that should do the trick I guess.

Comment: doesn't works and as per documentation shouldn't work also anyways thanks for posting.

Comment: Which documentation are you talking about? I did the same thing once and it worked for me. Reduces the pain of preventing default actions(submit here). Considering, you're not really submitting the form the traditional way.I had added a Button element instead of input type="submit" though. For a moment, I forgot input type="button" is deprecated now. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have included the jquery library in your page,

First, run your page with with your firefox/chrome and use their firebug/console to verify that your ajax is actually posting data to your php page.

Second, modify your query execution in your php file, to catch query errors:

```
mysql_query($postdata) or die(mysql_error());
```

One of these cases will help you determine your problem

For Firefox: get the Firebug addon from https://getfirebug.com/
After installing it and restarting firefox, press F12. A console will open.
Run your ajax call and check in the console if data are being posted.

Comment: Query is working fine i have tried without ajax and its doing what it's meant to be.  Second can you guide me how to "to verify that your ajax is actually posting data to your php page."

Comment: @sanki i have added instructions for firefox in my answer

Comment: No its not posting data

Comment: @sanki ok here is your problem.. you must debug your javascript code.
do you have jquery included? are you on document ready state?
possible javascript erros?

Comment: Wrapping it into a function was the issue. Anyways I really appreciate your participation. thanks